# Get handle HWND of input text control in electron

Tags: node.js, windows, electron, ime

I have a problem that is related between control in Electron of Node.js and HWND type in Windows. I needs to directly connect with the Input Method Editor in Window OS. There are some functions that can change IME such as: ImmReleaseContext() and ImmGetContext(hWnd).

The parameter of these above function is the type of HWND.

In Electron, I can not get the HWND of this "Input Text control of electron"?
Or can you leave me some hints to solve this problem?

Thanks for your helps.

Comment: I don't think Chromium uses a separate handle per text box.

Comment: Thanks, I know the concept of Windows is that all controls is considered as child window, so they are the type of HWND. But in electron, only the document of html is embedded in BrowserWindow of electron that can be got the handle by the function getNativeWindowHandle(). But can you leave me some suggestion about to connect with ImmGetContext()?

Comment: `all controls is considered as child window, so they are the type of HWND.`: that's for any native w32 control. Chromiumi's dom element is not w32 native control have hwnd.